# Linking JComboBox with SQL

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

I am writing a code to make a list in `JComboBox` using the data in the database.
It's actually for a POS system, where i have to select an item from a list in the database..

Here is the code i have been trying:
(i did take try it without the `while(itemsList != null)` .. but it didnt work either

```
private class ButtonHandlerSales implements ActionListener 
{ 
    public final String userName = "root";
    private final String password = "";
    private final String serverName = "localhost";
    private final int portNumber = 3306;
    private final String dbName = "alphapos";



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) 
    {   
        Connection conn = null;
        try 
        {
            conn = this.getConnection();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Connected to database");

        while(itemsList != null)
        {
            String[] list= null;
            String command = "SELECT itemName FROM item";

            try 
            {
                list = viewTable(conn, command);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            itemList = new JComboBox(list);


        }


    }

    private String[] viewTable(Connection con, String command) throws SQLException 
    {
        String list[] = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try 
        {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);

            int i=0;
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                list[i] = rs.getString("itemName");
                i++;
            }

        } 

        catch (SQLException e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally
        {
            if (stmt != 
            null) { stmt.close(); }
        }

        return list;

    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException 
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/" + this.dbName,
                connectionProps);

        return conn;
    }

}//end of class
```

I'm not getting any errors.. the code compiles.. but im not getting any output (list is empty).. 
Am i doing something wrong here?

Any help is really appreciated... ( im not looking for straight up codes )

Comment: I'm going to assume you are getting a NullPointerException: `String list[] = null`... `list[i] = rs.getString("itemName");`?

Comment: Yea.. i just tried with a System.println of the list.. :/ any clue why? Isnt the list[i] = rs.getString("itemName"); inputting values into list?

Comment: You need to initialize the `list[]`. Better to use something dynamic like `ArrayList` though, since you don't know how many results there will be. You can easily turn an `ArrayList` to an array.

Comment: Also I see no reason for the `while(itemsList != null)`

Comment: @peeskillet thanks! that totally worked! :) .. but it only works when i perform the "action" .. any clue how to make it otherwise? (ive done this in popups before, but in that the button press was the trigger.. what will be the trigger here? Where should this code belong?
I used the while loop coz i didnt know where else to put it.. :/

Comment: What _do_ you want to be the trigger? You want it to load on application start?

Comment: Yep.. I tried without the while loop, still the same, have to press a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

In your `viewTable` method `String list[] = null;`. You never initialize it with a `new String[..]`. So you will new a `NullPointerException`. But it would be better to use an `ArrayList`, since you may not know exactly how many values will be returned

```
private List<String> viewTable(Connection con, String command) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getString("itemName"));
    }
    return list;
}
```

### Problem 2

You are creating the `JComboBox` in the `ActionListener`. So you can't add the combo before the action is performed. With combo boxes, it's preferred to work with it's model, rather then the component, when working with the data. `JComboBox` has a `ComboBoxModel`. We can use the concrete [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html). You can pass an array to its constructor. `List`, has the method `toArray` we can call to create an array from the `List`. Then just pass the array to the `DefaultComboBoxModel` constructor and call the combo box `setModel`

```
List<String> list = null;
String command = "SELECT itemName FROM item";

try {
    list = viewTable(conn, command);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());
itemList.setModel(model);
```

This way, you can initialize the combo box before the action is performed.

---

### Update

If you want the combo box loaded on application start up, I don't see what the problem is. Just create a method in you class, using the code in the `actionPerformed`. Then just call that method, like in your main constructor or something. Maybe you could do something like below, where you have the method return a `ComboBoxModel` and you can use to set the model for the combo box

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    private final JComboBox itemList;

    public Test() throws SQLException {
        itemList = new JComboBox(viewTable(getConnection(), command));
        JButton button = new JButton("Populate");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(itemList);
        panel.add(button);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                ComboBoxModel model = viewTable(getConnection(), command);
                itemList.setModel(model);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    private ComboBoxModel viewTable(Connection con, String command) throws SQLException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);

            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(rs.getString("itemName"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());

    }

    public final String userName = "root";
    private final String password = "";
    private final String serverName = "localhost";
    private final int portNumber = 3306;
    private final String dbName = "alphapos";
    private final String command = "select itemName from item";

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/" + this.dbName,
                connectionProps);

        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i used arraylist i had a classcastexception.. Will `List<String> list = null;` help with that?

Comment: Did you run my code. It works (I had to create a database, but it works as posted). See if you can incorporate into your real code. The combo will be populated on startup as well as re-populated on button press

Comment: I tried it on a saperate project file.. I seem to get a ... sort of log. `<ConnectionProperties>
 <PropertyCategory name="Connection/Authentication">
  <Property name="user" required="No" default="" sortOrder="-2147483647" since="all versions">
    The user to connect as
  </Property>
  <Property name="password" required="No" default="" sortOrder="-2147483646" since="all versions">
    The password to use when connecting
  </Property>` ...

Comment: Did you set the password? Other than that, I don't know what to tell you. It works fine for me

Comment: No password on my db... :/ I'll try to grasp the concept of it then :)

Comment: Have you been able to connect to the DB at all before, using jdbc?